# How is a CoreMIDI Thru Connection made in swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, coremidi

The following builds and runs and prints the non error console message at the end when passed two valid MIDIEndPointRefs. But midi events are not passed thru from source to dest as expected. Is something missing?

```
func createThru2(source:MIDIEndpointRef?, dest:MIDIEndpointRef?)  {

    var connectionRef = MIDIThruConnectionRef()
    var params = MIDIThruConnectionParams()
    MIDIThruConnectionParamsInitialize(&params)

    if let s = source {
        let thruEnd = MIDIThruConnectionEndpoint(endpointRef: s, uniqueID: MIDIUniqueID(1))
        params.sources.0 = thruEnd
        params.numSources = 1
        print("thru source is \(s)")
    }

    if let d = dest {
        let thruEnd = MIDIThruConnectionEndpoint(endpointRef: d, uniqueID: MIDIUniqueID(2))
        params.destinations.0 = thruEnd
        params.numDestinations = 1
        print("thru dest is \(d)")
    }

    var localParams = params
    let nsdata = withUnsafePointer(to: &params) { p in
        NSData(bytes: p, length: MIDIThruConnectionParamsSize(&localParams))
    }

    let status = MIDIThruConnectionCreate(nil, nsdata, &connectionRef)
    if status == noErr {
        print("created thru")
    } else {
        print("error creating thru \(status)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in Swift 5 on macOS 10.13.6. A thru connection is established and MIDI events are passed from source to destination. So the problem does not seem to be the function you posted, but in the endpoints you provided or in using Swift 4.2.

I used the following code to call your function:

```
var source:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetSource(5)
var dest:MIDIEndpointRef = MIDIGetDestination(9)

createThru2(source:source, dest:dest)
```

5 is a MIDI keyboard and 9 is a MIDI port on my audio interface.

Comment: My answer clarifies that the code provided is working correctly. So please don't delete it so others can learn from it. I would have left a comment instead but the reputation system won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. I just tested this same code on Swift 5 and OS X 12.4, and it doesn't seem to work for me. `MIDIThruConnectionCreate` returns `noErr`, but no MIDI packets seem to flow.

I'm using the MIDIKeys virtual source, and MIDI Monitor virtual destination.

I'll try it with some hardware and see what happens.

Comment: Same issue here. I've been trying all day to troubleshoot this. Even wrote a bare-bones pure Obj-C project that attempts to create a thru connection and there is no MIDI data flow.